# Entity Framework map multiple level properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cross-apply

I am trying to implement a hierarchical inheritance structure in Entity Framework, specifically for settings. For example, lets say we have user preferences:

```
public class StorePreference: Preference { }

public class UserPreference : Preference { }

public class Preference {
public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
public ContactMethod ContactMethod { get; set; }
}

public enum ContactMethod {
  SMS,
  Email
}
```

I'd like it so that if I lookup the user's preferences. If the user doesn't exist or the property value is null, it looks up the parent (store) default preferences.

Ideally, i'd like it to work similar to abstract inheritance:

```
public class UserPreference : StorePreference {
    private string _backgroundColor;

    public string BackgroundColor {
        get { 
           if (this._backgroundColor == null)
              return base;

           return this._backgroundColor;
        } 
        set { this._backgroundColor = value; }
    }
}
```

If I were to write this as a SQL query, it'd be a CROSS APPLY with a CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN User.BackgroundColor == null THEN Store.BackgroundColor ELSE User.BackgroundColor END BackgroundColor,
    CASE WHEN User.ContactMethod == null THEN Store.ContactMethod ELSE User.ContactMethod END ContactMethod
FROM UserPreference User
CROSS APPLY StorePreference Store
WHERE UserPreference.UserId = @UserId
```

Is there a way I can achieve loading this in EF?

Answer (score 0):

In your base class add default property values:

```
public class Preference {
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; } = "Red";
    public ContactMethod ContactMethod { get; set; } = ContactMethod.SMS;
}
```

Something like this to set from database:

```
public class StorePreference : Preference { }

public class UserPreference : Preference { }

public class Preference {
    public Preference() {
        BackgroundColor = DefaultPreference.BackgroundColor;
        ContactMethod = DefaultPreference.ContactMethod;
    }

    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public ContactMethod ContactMethod { get; set; }

    public DefaultPreference DefaultPreference { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultPreference {
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public ContactMethod ContactMethod { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This hard codes the default. I want them to be in the database so that the default could be changed

Comment: Can you make Preference defaults it's own object, like `DefaultPreference` and then set the defaults in the constructor?

Comment: I just updated the answer to reflect a DefaultPreference object that would have to be separate if you wanted it from the database.

Comment: This would make `UserPreference` use values from `Preference` instead of `StorePreference` if it were null and doesn't answer the issue if the record for the user didn't exist in the UserPreference table

Comment: So it seems like you are looking for an auto-magic solution with a single attribute or something that would set database values based on another table while checking for null, including having the new object not even exist yet, without actually getting the default values from the DB until save time?You are going to have to write some code to achieve this outside the class. There is no automated EF solution to achieving this. Do you have some other framework or language you can reference that does what you're asking that you're looking for the equivalent of?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the properties are public, entity won't have a problem pulling the data from another table as the default. You would need to create a private field to hold the data if you used a setter:

```
public class ChildTable : EntityBase {
    private string _someCategory;

    [Key]
    [Column(name: "CHILD_ID")]
    public override int Id { get; protected set; }

    [Column(name: "SOME_CATEGORY")]
    public string SomeCategory {
        get { return _someCategory; }
        set { _someCategory = value ?? ParentTable.SomeCategory; }
    }

    [ForeignKey("ParentTable")]
    [Column(name: "PARENT_ID")]
    public int ParentTableId { get; set; }

    public virtual ParentTable ParentTable { get; set; }
}
```

This is just an alternative to a constructor, if you need more control over the setter logic, otherwise Austin's answer would be simpler to implement